# Error when modifying variable "Property or indexer '' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game with a code like this:

```
[SerializeField, FixedNumber]
        private long _speed = FixedMath.One * 4;

        public virtual long Speed
        {
            get { return _speed ; }
        }
```

Which I need to change the `Speed` at runtime. But I got this error:

> `XXX' cannot be assigned to (it is read only)

I can make change in `inspector`. But I need to change it with script. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get { return _speed; }` is **read only** because you only have `get` accessor which will only allow you get the `value`. To make it possible to write to the `Speed` property, you must include the `set` accessor too.

```
private long _speed = FixedMath.One * 4;
public virtual long Speed
{
    get { return _speed; }
    set
    {
        _speed = value;
    }
}
```